Java Treeset not removing duplicate user defined object with custom compareTo
I try to remove duplicate object, duplicate when _id is the same or email is the same. I'm trying to eliminate duplicate if ids are the same OR emails are the same then keep the record with the latest Date.
My custom CompareTo:
 @Override
    public int compareTo(Lead other) {
         
        // Compare by ID first
        int idComparison = this._id.compareTo(other._id);
        if (idComparison != 0) {
            return idComparison;
        }
        
        int emailComparison = this.email.compareTo(other.email);
        if (emailComparison != 0) {
                return emailComparison;
       }

        
        // If IDs are the same, compare by date (latest first)
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            Date date1 = dateFormat.parse( this.entryDate);
            Date date2 = dateFormat.parse( other.entryDate);

            return date1.compareTo(date2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            return 0; // Handle parsing errors appropriately
        }

My declared and initialized
 // convert the JSON data to a Java object
        LeadsData leads = gson.fromJson(reader, LeadsData.class);

        // Remove duplicates using TreeSet
        TreeSet<Lead> uniqueRecords = new TreeSet<>(leads.leads);

I'm not sure where I did wrong. I checked Treeset doc, it seems quite straightforward.

Shouldn't you  @Override equals and hashcode to determine if things are equal?

Also, you might want to store a proper datetime object. The ones you're using should no longer be used though, so you can simplify, using your existing string type, to return LocalDateTime.parse(this.entryDate).compareTo(LocalDateTime.parse(other.entryDate));

Not what you asked, do not store your dates and times as strings in your objects. And don’t use Date and SimpleDateFormat at all since they were troublesome and are long outdated. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. From your format it seems that you would want LocalDateTime for your date and time, though I wonder that depending in circumstances and requirements ZonedDateTime or Instant may be a still better choice. Either implements Comparable.

If you neither want duplicate IDs nor duplicate emails, sorting by ID should suffice, and you can leave out the remainder of your compareTo method. I would use a different mechanism to deduplicate email addresses, it should not be the job of the compareTo method since two objects with identical email may have IDs that are far apart.

“duplicate when _id is the same or email is the same” — don’t you mean when id and email are the same? and, not or?

As a side note, this specific pattern allows to compare the dates in their string form; you don’t have to parse them. If you want to check them for correctness, the compare method is not the right place to do this; it should happen when you import the data.

So given leads with (id, email): (1, e@aol.com), (1, e@apple.com), (3, e@apple.com) and (3, e@hotmail.com), should all of these be considered equal? And only the one with the latest date kept? I severely doubt that a TreeSet<Lead> alone can do this for you.

An idea would be: Keep two maps (HashMap is a fine choice), a Map<ID, Lead> for looking up by ID and a Map<String, Lead> for looking up by email. When you receive a new lead, look it up in both maps. If found in one or the other or both (which is possible too), delete from both maps any lead that hasn’t got the most recent date, then insert the most recent one into both maps if not already there. Maybe for easy and simplicity just unconditionally delete from both maps and then unconditionally insert.

Apparently you are asking to eliminate duplicate objects where “duplicate” means having both the same id and the same email. But then you test for a third field, a date-time string. So the same id and email cannot be considered duplicates unless the date-time is also the same.
Example:
record Lead ( int id , String email , String when ) {}

Lead x = new Lead ( 1 , "alice@example.com" , "2024-01-23T12:30:00" ) ;
Lead y = new Lead ( 1 , "alice@example.com" , "2024-11-07T09:00:00" ) ;

These are not duplicates by your rules. The date-time text differs, so these two objects are not equal given your three-field test.

By the way, you can greatly simplify your code using the convenience methods found on Comparator. This untested code might work:
SequencedSet < Lead > leads =
    new TreeSet <> (
        Comparator
        .comparing ( Lead :: id ) 
        .thenComparing ( Lead :: email ) 
        .thenComparing ( Comparator.comparing ( Lead :: when ).reversed() )
    );
leads.addAll( myLeads ) ;

Our example above should sort in the order: [ y , x ].

I'm trying to eliminate duplicate if ids are the same OR emails are the same then keep the record with the latest Date. I'm not sure how to achieve that using comparator?
